# SSL certification for multiple domains

Tags: ssl, https

For a serverfarm with a tracking solution for several clients, I need a SSL certificate for multiple domains (3 different ones) and on each of the domains for all the subdomains.

I do only need it to get the tracking pixels without any browser warnings when embedded in https pages on client side. It is NOT used for security issues or so.

What might be the best product for my use-case?

Thanks

Comment: are you saying you want a self-signed cert, or you just want us to tell you where to buy one?

Comment: i'd like to know if there is something like a "multi domain" certificate, whether it is a good idea to book this instead of 3 single domain certificates and if there is a recommendation also where to get it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can get SSL certificates that cover multiple domains -- they're usually called "multi-domain" or "universal communication" certificates, and they will have a single CN and a lengthy list of subjectAltNames.  Most providers will sell you one, but it might cost you stupid amounts of money.  We don't do provider recommendations, though (because who is who in the zoo changes so quickly).  They're popular for people who want to do SSL on a number of domains, but don't want to (or can't) chew a lot of IP addresses (EC2 hosting, for instance).

Comment: is a multi-domain SSL cert also called a wildcard SSL cert, or is there a special name for the cert when it covers everthing under a TLD?

Comment: No, a multi-domain cert is differenr to a wildcard cert.  You're not (legitimately) going to get a wildcard cert that covers everything under a TLD, because that would allow you to MITM a large number of sites.

Comment: Sorry for the completely off-topic question, but what kind of SSL cert do people use for https proxies within an organization?  Those certs must cover all domains, no?

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question.  It's quite appropriate as a question in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3rd party companies issuing SSL certificates which can be used for multiple domains and subdomains. These are called SAN (Subject Alternate Names) certificates. These are priced bit higher than standard 1 domain based SSL certificates. You can buy those certificates for certain number of SANs (Subject Alternate Names or domains and sub-domains). Initially you can specify all the domains/sub-domains for which you need the certificate for. But if you dont know all the domains/sub-domains right in the beginning, you can get it for few domains and then during its validity period you can get it reissued by adding more domains as Subject alternate names.